# Python Formatting with %d

Tags: python

I am trying to format the amount of hundreds using %d

```
amount = [10]
print "Hundreds %d"(amount[0])
```

I am then getting a TypeError saying 'str' is not callable. This is my first time using this formatting, so any help would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: It is [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) to use `str.format()` instead of `%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the modulo (`%`) operator:

```
print "Hundreds %d" % (amount[0])
```

---

Note however that the modern way to do this is to use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "Hundreds {}".format(amount[0])
```